# cv::Mat_<Type> allocation error

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to instantiate a cv::Mat with a custom defined type, but the allocation seems to be failing. For example:

```
struct SType
{
    int a;
    char c[16];
};

cv::Mat m = cv::Mat_<SType>(1, 1);

printf("cols = %i rows %i step = %zi elemSize = %zi elemSize1 = %zi\n",
       m.cols, m.rows, m.step[0], m.elemSize(), m.elemSize1() );
```

this provides the following output:

```
cols = 1 rows 1 step = 8 elemSize = 8 elemSize1 = 8
```

which is obviously wrong, since I'm expecting a elemSize of 20. Is this a bug or the cv::Mat_ wrapper is not supposed to be used with custom element types?

Edit:

When assigning the instance to a cv::Mat_ element instead

```
cv::Mat_<SType> m = cv::Mat_<SType>(1, 1);

printf("cols = %i rows %i step = %zi elemSize = %zi elemSize1 = %zi\n",
       m.cols, m.rows, m.step[0], m.elemSize(), m.elemSize1() );
```

I get the following output:

```
cols = 1 rows 1 step = 8 elemSize = 20 elemSize1 = 20
```

Now, elemSize is correct, but step is wrong. As I understand, step is used to compute the specific element to access in the matrix via the operator() (row,col), and I'm observing problems when doing so. Anybody has a better insight on what's going on here?

Edit 2:

I submitted a bug report regarding this issue. http://code.opencv.org/issues/4415 . In the meantime, if anyone has an idea how to deal with it, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: usually, you would have to define some [traits](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/traits.hpp) for your new type (and i do not see that working with your 'mixed' struct)

Answer (score 0):

I think I spotted the mistake. You declare your variable as cv::Mat. Try:

```
cv::Mat_<SType> m = cv::Mat_<SType>(1, 1);
```

Comment: My understanding is that cv::Mat_ is just a wrapper around cv::Mat, so it shouldn't make any difference. I'll try it anyway and let you know if it makes a difference.